# Previous screen closes when I go back from another (calls onDestroy)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a Home and Login screens. In the Home screen I call the Login screen.

The problem is when I am in Login and go back to Home. The aplication calls onDestroy of Home and closes.

Here's the code:

```
public class Home extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        final ImageView login_username_btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login_username_btn);

        login_username_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}


public class Login extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        final EditText etUsuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsuario);
        final EditText etSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSenha);
        final ImageView ivVoltar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.voltarBtn);

        ivVoltar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById(android.R.id.content)
                    .getWindowToken(), 0);

                finish();
            }
        });


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById(android.R.id.content)
            .getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}


And on LogCat shows "GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed" and "GC_EXPLICIT freed" messages.
```

Comment: And on LogCat shows "GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed" and "GC_EXPLICIT freed" messages.

I don't know if it's normal.

Comment: add your declaration of activities in the manifest xml

Comment: you have finished your acitvity on `ivVoltar` onClickListener remove `finish();`

Comment: Try to use current Activity `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` while creating the intent. Also, check manifest file, if login activity has any special launch mode defined.

Comment: Removing the `finish()` the screen will not close when I click the back button (`ivVoltar`).

Comment: And I don't know why, but I can substitute `getApplicationContext()` by `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To back to Home you are calling `finish();`, that destroys the activity (Finishing the activity is already after onClose()).

[image]

Instead of it create an intent to HomeActivity. That solves the problem.

```
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), HomeActivity.class);
```

Or

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    super.onBackPressed();
}

ivVoltar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById(android.R.id.content)
                .getWindowToken(), 0);

            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Comment: But I have to call `finish()`, don't I?? 'Cause Login screen is in the top of stack and below is Home screen. Calling `finish()` I close the Login and restart the Home, am I right??

Comment: I make it show all the states of the app and realised that the Home screen called `onPause()` and after `onDestroy()`, didn't call `onStop()`. And also didn't call `onStart()`. Why?!

Comment: As you can see the app can be destroyed if the phone need memory to prior apps. maybe that was why it didn't passed by `onStop()`. But I can't say tell you anything for sure because I don't see your app's cycle...

Comment: normally , calling finish() will destroy the LoginActivity , and then the HomeActivity should be displayed unless if it is not registered in the Stack of Activities ( android:noHistory="true" in manifest )

Comment: It's strange, 'cause it isn't displaying the Home. It is calling `onStop()` after close the Login.

Comment: What are you using to close it? (The idea is to call `onStop()` instead of `onDestroy()`, no?